# How to set up machine specifc sql scripts using Flyway and spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, database-migration, flyway

I need to set up Flyway such that certain sql scripts are run in UAT instances and certain sql scripts are run in production instances. How do I go about implementing this? Should I have two different sets of configuration files specific to each machine? Or should I use `flyway.locations` property to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring-Profiles (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) and define on each profile a other location.

Otherwise you can define an environment-variable (`spring.flyway.location=${ENV_VAR:defaultPath}`).

And the last option: Implement Flyway the "manual way". See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks